# can php cron jobs access session variables/cookies?

Tags: php, cron

i am new to cron jobs and i have done much searching on this topic but i couldn't understand it fully. can cron jobs access cookies or session variables?

thanks!

Comment: You should really have specified the use case in which this access would be necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A cron job won't be able to access cookies, since by definition it is not being invoked from a web browser request. Only the web browser stores a cookie, which contains the session id. No web browser, no cookie, no session.

Having said that, if you *do* know the session id somehow, you should be able to start the session manually by feeding the id into [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) before using `session_start()`.

Comment: And that is only if the session still exists. A cron job running, say, hour or days later will probably try to load a session that doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice Answer. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer is that one can use session-cookie files with command-line web clients.
example:

```
C=~/tmp/x
WGET="wget --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=$C --save-cookies=$C"
```

## 1. get the login page

```
$WGET -O index.html "http://mail.yahoo.com"
```

## 2. fish out any hidden values

```
HIDDENVARS=`cat index.html | tr '\r\n\t' ' ' | tr -s ' ' | sed "s|> *<|>~<|g" | tr '~' '\n' | \
grep -i "<input .*hidden" | sed "s|.*name=\"\([^\"]*\)\".*value=\"\([^\"]*\)\".*$|\1=\2|g" | tr '\n' '&'`
```

## 3 manually add non-hidden vars

FORMVARS=".persistent=y&login=USERNAME&passwd=SECRET"

## 4. post form-data to the target

$WGET -O login.html --post-data="${HIDDENVARS}&${FORMVARS}" "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?"

## 5. profit ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called [pseudo cron](http://www.bitfolge.de/?l=en&s=pseudocron) that i suppose would be able to access session and/or cookies. But it would make no sense to me.

Comment: Not really. By running from an actual request, it "sees" the cookies from the person requesting the page at that exact moment, not the cookies from the person whose cron-job you're running.
The same restriction @deceze cite would apply here. You'd need to know beforehand the *session_id* and use it to start a session. Which them makes pseudo-cron not a good option unless you can't use cron.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I thought it was relevant since the question made no reference to which particular session to access. But given you want to access a session with a known session id the answer from deceze would be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

**A time-based, server-side "cookie" to run within a cron job:**

Use file() to read the server-side "cookie" - a text file.

Use fopen,fwrite,fclose to write the server-side "cookie".

Use implode if storing more than one datavalue in your "cookie":

**Main code:**

```
<?php

$username = 'whatever';

$usercookie = 'http://yourdomainname.com/cookiebank/'.$username.'cookie.txt';

$oldtime = file($usercookie);

if(is_array($oldtime)) {
   $cookievalue = implode(" ",$oldtime);  
}
else {
   $cookievalue = $oldtime;
}

// $cookievalue can then be used as you wish...

$newtime = date("M j G:i:s");

$newtime = strtotime($newtime)*1000;  // current time in msec

$myfile = fopen($usercookie, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $newtime);
fclose($myfile);


echo 'done';

?>
```

An approach straight from the mind of Heath Robinson - not very elegant but it works if you want to apply a cookie-like behaviour to a cron job.