# php send mail using cron jobs

Tags: php, cron

I have two file 'mail.php' and 'cron.php' . 'mail.php' receives email address from a source continuously . 'cron.php' will send email to those address at the next hour of receiving hour .If email address is received at 5.45 email will be sent at 6.00 .
My idea is to run cron.php every hour which will get email addresses and their receiving time form session variable.
But how can I synchronise this two file ?? Is it possible to access session variable simultaneously by this two file ?? that means mail.php will write data and after sending mail cron.php will delete those data from session.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to post some code up. I dont really understand what you mean. The first part of your weustion leads me too believe that you have something setup already, whereas the latter half doesn't.

Basically what you need to do, is have mail.php (the one that gets the email addresses from wherever there coming) and store those somewhere (database or plain text file maybe). Then every hour, run the cron, grab the emails, do whatever you need to do then either elete thos eemails, archive them in another place if you need to keep them, or if your using a database you could use an "email_sent" column and set it to 1 once the emails have been sent.

Answer (score 2):

Answer about session and CRON here.
[can php cron jobs access session variables/cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699423/can-php-cron-jobs-access-session-variables-cookies)

If I were you I'll save the email addresses in database or a text file.
And then delete them after executed.

Comment: nice idea :) ... i didn't think about it

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just make a function for sending emails (turn mail.php into a function?) and call it with cron.php?

Comment: Maybe OP doesn't want to put too much load on server. Pulling DB and sending mail. In my company we split tasks like this into 2 too, just like this case.

Comment: cron.php will run after every 1 hour . meanwhile mail.php should receive email address.so I think both of them should run independently .

Comment: Right, I didn't fully understand the question. You can store the addresses from mail.php into a CSV file, and then in cron.php grab those addresses, send emails, and clean the CSV file. That should make as less server load as possible.